# ExecuteScalar doesnt return the ID of the record after saving it

Tags: database, vb.net, oledb, oledbconnection

I am developing windows application using VB.NET and MS ACCESS for back end. 
I am saving the record by using the below code...

below code working fine , it saves the record but cmd.ExecuteScalar() not working at all , it doesn't return the saved ID of the record. It returns the 0.

```
   Try
        Dim cn As New ConnectionPool
        cn.open()
        Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("", cn.Connection)
        _NewIdentity = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar())
        SetColumn(IdentityColumnName, _NewIdentity)
        cn.close()
        bSuccess = True
    Catch ex As EntityException
        Throw ex
```

what changes should I make in above code ?

Answer (score 0):

Your table would need that ID field is marked as Identity and finally I would suggest to create a stored procedure to encapsulate the INSERT statement and right after it, include this T-SQL: Select SCOPE_IDENTITY() which is a function that lets you get the latest ID inserted in the scope it is executed.

Comment: thanks , it will be nice if you give me some link for sample...where I can see exactly how I should write the code...

Comment: Sure, here is a good example http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/54/Getting-the-identity-of-the-most-recently-added-record

Comment: ok, I will check that, but what wrong in my code ? It works fine when I use SQL server as DB , when I use MS ACCESS it doesn't works...